# How to provide multiple choice in generated Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel-2007, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm working on an application that generates a series of Excel files where users need to enter information for school grades. One of the sections requires the user to enter a value from a selection of three possibilities.

I thought it would make sense to do this with ActiveX radio buttons. However, I noticed that the size of the files increased heavily when using these controls and that the files become somewhat unresponsive when opening. Note that I have a few hundred to a thousand radio buttons, depending on the amount of information is required.

Is there any advice or ideas on alternative approaches to this? Would it help to use the older form controls (non-ActiveX) in order to keep file size low and increase responsiveness? Or will I not have enough options to work with the older controls, given that at a later stage I also need to read the Excel files and the input of the users?

FWIW, I'm using the following code to create new radio buttons:

```
worksheet.OLEObjects().Add(ClassType: "Forms.OptionButton.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Validation for the cells.  You simply create a named ra(nge somewhere and use Data Validation -> List and the user will get a combo box in the cell with the choices in the list specified.
If you want to store the list (options) in another sheet, you need to create a named range.